# How can I send text to the Orca Screen Reader from C++

Tags: c++, accessibility, screen-readers

I want to send text to the Orca screen reader (or other AT-SPI compatible screen readers) from a C++ application under Linux. But, I don't want this to be in a GTK application. The application may not even have a window. It's for a blind user. I can communicate with espeak directly and make my program talk, but it talks over the screen reader, so you get two voices at the same time. If I could send to Orca, my application would be able to add speech to the queue of things to say and not talk over.

I can't use Atk for this, since it assumes a GTK application. I see libatspi, but it always assumes user visual interface components, not stand-alone applications specifically for blind people who do not need the window interface at all. I've also not found any simple examples of using libatspi.

Comment: Just found this question due to the tags. If you are making something for a blind user, I wouldn't bother with espeak and make everything accessible. If you still want to make it talk, you may be able to sniff if Orca is running and do something.